# COUNT from database vs increment

Tags: mysql, sql

Which method would be better to use for getting the number of likes?

Assuming I have the table likes:

[image]

so like_type is to determine what type is id_liked. So if like_type is "question" and the id_liked is 10 then the like belongs to this row:

```
SELECT * FROM questions where question_id = 10;
```

if like_type is "answer" the row with the answer will be

```
SELECT * FROM answers where answer_id = 10;
```

[image]

So the main question is: Which method is best to get all question with id 10 likes?

```
SELECT COUNT() as like_numbers from likes where like_type = `question` AND id_liked = 10;
```

OR

Every time when someone like a question increment question_likes from questions table so would not be necessary to count every time.

Comment: This really depends on what you want to use the data for.  If all you care about is the number of `Likes`, then you should just increment it.  But if you care about the data behind the `Likes` (e.g.: who liked whom, when, what, etc.) then you should store that separately and do a `COUNT()` when needed.

Comment: If I have 10 questions per page and wanna show the number of likes for that questions I must do 10 COUNT() but if I store the count in question_likes then I will skyp 10 COUNT(). Yes I need to know who gaved that like.

Comment: It seems you need to store the "like" information anyways.  
Option 1 : If you want to increment, then you need to perform two DML operation, insert into like table and update question table.  Slowing the like process.
Option 2: Just do insert into like table and  select whenever needed.
and just run a job at the end of the day to update the question_likes field of question table, for your downstream application ( if you care about them )

Comment: The incremented field is simpler; however, you lose the ability for "likers" to rescind their like. An alternative is to have both. You can even set up triggers on the likes table to increment the relevant counter.

Comment: You could still do 1 query to get the count of any number of questions using grouping. `SELECT question_id, count(*) as like_numbers FROM likes WHERE like_type='question' AND id_liked IN (801, 802, 803, 804[...etc. list of question ids to query]) GROUP BY question_id`. obviously fix the list of question ids. Or you could also query out the count as a correlated subquery with the questions: `SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE like_type='question' AND id_liked=questions.id) AS like_numbers FROM questions WHERE ...`

Comment: @Sagar would not be ok cuz users may think the website has a bug because is not counting the likes. And the next day after cron to appear all the likes. I think the best method is to use both solutions and create a trigger when I make a insert in likes table to increment the value from questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on several factors. Here are some pros and cons so you can decide for yourself.

## Incrementing a number

#### Pros

- Easier and more performant to lookup a single number.
- Easy to modify to skew results.

#### Cons

- People can likely find a way to like multiple times.
- Can't count individual likes if they need to be recalculated.
- Can't remove likes for stuff like a user was deleted/banned.

---

### Storing individual likes

#### Pros

- Can be re-calculated if the numbers get skewed for some reason.
- More verbose, you can literally count the likes yourself.
- Can store identifying information with the likes to prevent multiple likes for same question or answer.
- Can remove a vote if a user is deleted/banned (or just don't count votes from those users).

#### Cons

- Less performant to count many rows, especially if the number gets really, really high (think [m|b|tr]illions+).
- Uses more space. Likely not an issue, but when you have tons of rows, it might. Would need quite a lot though.

---

The forum software my website uses I believe does both. Each post has a thumbs up button and it stores a count with each row but also keeps record of each individual vote. As an admin I can edit the count to another number which only adjusts the count but I can hover the number on the post and see who voted it up. There is also a "recalculate all post scores" option in the admin panel that will go over and readjust the number to what the actual votes were.

Comment: I think the best method is to use both solutions and create a trigger when I make a insert in likes table to increment the value from questions.

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure if our software does this as a trigger, transaction (used to run multiple queries as one batch db update) or just as separate queries. I haven't had an issue, so I've never actually looked.

Comment: @IonVasile don't forget a delete trigger as well, to decrement if the row is deleted.

Comment: I think I will add a like_status column enum with: "active", "suspended", "deleted" so if I set user_status as "deleted" from users table the trigger automatically set for that user likes like_status "deleted". Is that ok?

And @JonathanKuhn for example if you manipulate the likes and set 10 likes to a post where 4 people liked, if you hover over the number would appear 4 people yes? Would not be suspicious?

Comment: Yes, I would only see 4 people. However I only see those as an admin. Normal users do not. My site actually has a few forums with up/down votes and it uses the same system. Normal users shouldn't see who is downvoting them for retaliation reasons. I see see it as an admin.

Comment: Well on my website I have only the like button and I would like to make the option to see who liked their questions or answers. So if the question have 10 likes and only 4 people appear there would be suspicious.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and consider the: cache database query scenario?

Comment: In what way are you suggesting caching? As a column on the table? Or through some other php caching method? I'm assuming you mean caching as in using a trigger to update a column on the table.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html will save the select query on the server as files in a folder, and everytime a user make a insert by pressing the like button the cache are deleted and updated with the new value.

Comment: Yea, there are several mysql caching options to cache queries and results. That works fine and would save some performance as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87421/discussion-between-ion-vasile-and-jonathan-kuhn).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your specific needs, expected concurrency, and complexity of your application.

Caching a column with the current count on the `questions` table is likely to be more efficient if you're already reading that table to generate a listing of questions.

It *could* require additional application logic if, for example, a user's likes need to be removed from the totals if their account get suspended or such (since just pulling them from the `likes` table wouldn't remove them from the cached count).  Even if you have conditions like this, you have to decide if the performance benefit is worth adding additional logic in your scenario.

Another option is generating the cached count on a schedule via a cronjob or other mechanism.  This can minimize your impact on your application logic and MySQL's query cache, but also adds a level of complexity to something which in your case seems to be low-impact (the cost of adding to the count when adding a like is low).

If you add an index to the `id_liked` column, it will improve the performance of counting likes from that table—but you'll still have the overhead of a `JOIN` or a separate query for each record when connecting this to your questions.

Note: If you're adding to a count column of some type, make sure you do it atomically within MySQL so you aren't wiping out likes that happen between querying the current count and when you update the value:

`` UPDATE `questions` SET `question_likes`=(`question_likes`+1) WHERE [...condition...] ``

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet would be to go with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT() as like_numbers from likes where id_liked = 10 AND like_type = question;
```

But add an index on id_liked, like_type.

With the second option you may have slightly faster query response under heavy liking of questions and answers, but you will also have more work to develop and a potential maintenance issue down the road when your count somehow gets out of sync.